# Getting error InvalidHeaderError when sending jet token via request.get

Tags: curl, python-requests, jwt

I have made a authentication using flask restplus. When user login it returns a jet token,

Now I also have a protected resource, I want to access the protected resource from command line.

So I think I can use requests but when I pass the authorization in header it doesn't work.

```
headers = { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json',  'Authorization: Bearer' : token_generated_from_login}

requests.get(protected_uri, headers=headers)
```

But I get error `InvalidHeaderError: Bad Authorization Header. Expected value 'Bearer <JWT>'`

But when I access from terminal using curl it works.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" http://localhost:5000/protected/resource
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out.

```
headers = { "Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(token)}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
response.status_code
201
```